# Using htaccess with Thrift

Tags: .htaccess, thrift

Can Thrift work when htaccess is used on a domain?

Our site works with Thrift, but once we add htaccess the site does not load. The non Thrift code load fine with htaccess. So I assume there is some special setup needed to make Apache Thrift work with htaccess, if it supports it. If so, can someone provide some direction here on how to set this up.

I can't find any info on google too for this so any help would be great from the thrift experts.

Thanks.